# how to route multiple segment in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3, multilingual

I see many well-known websites uses URI like these to provide different language

```
www.example.com/en/
www.example.com/fr/
```

but I get 404 error page when I try to open `www.mysite.com/en/user/david`

this is what my `User` controller looks like

```
class User extends MY_Controller {
  public function index($username='') {
    echo 'Hello, '.$username;
  }
}
```

and I tried adding this in my `config/routes.php`

```
$route['en/(\w.+)'] = '$1';
```

after reading up, I saw this in the [CI docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html):

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

is what I'm trying to do impossible? if not, how can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specific the method in your route config, check it [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html#routing)

```
http://example.com/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]
```

And you can change to this to get the username:

```
$route['en/(\w.+)/(\w.+)'] = '$1/index/$2';
```

If it still not works, maybe you need to add index.php in your url like this:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/en/user/david
```

or [remove it](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html?highlight=index%20php#removing-the-index-php-file)